# Assembly 80286: Accessing n-th byte of variable

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

(asm 80286)
Data segment variable accessing, on a array of type `byte` or `word`?

I am trying to access the n-th byte/ word of a variable but something is wrong and i dont know wha

```
ASSUME cs: code, ds:data 
data SEGMENT
    s db 5,1,2,3

data ENDS 
code SEGMENT 
start: 
mov ax,data 
mov es,ax 
mov si, 0;
    mov ax, 0;
    check:  
        cmp si, len   
        jg fin
        mov al, byte ptr [s][si] ; !!! this return not the value i i think it would
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        cmp al, 0
        jl  negativ   ; move to positiv 
        jmp positiv   ; move to negativ 

    positiv:
        mov byte ptr d1[si],al
        inc si
        jmp check
    negativ:  
        mov byte ptr d2[si],al
        inc si
        jmp check   
    fin:
mov ax,4C00h          
int 21h 
code ENDS 
END start
```

The get to debug : tasm name , tlink name, td name
The ^^^^^^^^ line is returning me wrong values, thats why i assume i checked with the debugger and the values are from data segment, but not the  correct ones.

I think I might not have understand  the addressing methods corectly, could anyone help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to initialise `DS`.

Change

```
mov ax,data 
mov es,ax
```

to

```
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax
mov es,ax
```

Is the initialisation of `ES` really needed?

Comment: For the name of god... been setting 2 days for this bug, thank you checking it now